# How redirect user to login page after try to execute ajax request if spring security session is timeout?

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, spring-security

I have spring boot app with spring security. I need check redirect to login page if user make request after session time out. I have 2 page: `login` and `index`. On `index` page I get requests by `Ajax`.

I open index page. wait 30 sec. Try update page after Session timeout but I not redirect to login page. But if I try update page `F5` spring redirect me to login page. But if I try make ajax request - it work find and I not redirect.

It is my configs:

```
http.authorizeRequests().
                antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").permitAll().defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and();
```

and button on index page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="reload()">show</button>
```

and js method:

```
function reload() {
        table.ajax.reload(null, false);
    }
```

When I press "show" button - my table send request to spring controller(Session already invalid) and controller return data and table update success/ But I need redirect user to login page.

Comment: Where did you set your session timeout time ?

Answer (score 0):

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
        // ??? .antMatchers("/", "/index/**").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/index")
        .and()
    .logout()           
         .logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
    .csrf()
        .disable();
```

Can you try this ? and `.antMatchers("/", "/index/**").hasRole("USER")` is very confused.